# JAX-WS Issue using wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am trying to make a simple project using JAX-WS. I am following this example: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/JEETT.pdf to be precise the head about JAX-WS. I have followed all of the steps. The difference is that I am using `wildfly` as a server and for IDE Eclipse which is important as I had to generate the `HelloService` from the command prompt. The code for the webservice:

```
@WebService

    public class Hello {

        private final String message = "Hello, ";

        public Hello() { 

        }

        @WebMethod
        public String sayHelloName(String name) {
            return message + name + ".";
        }
        @WebMethod
        public String sayHello() {
            return message + ".";
        }

    }
```

and the code for the servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "HelloServlet", urlPatterns = { "/HelloServlet" })
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1530081955969170723L;

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/SampleRest-web/Hello?wsdl")
    private HelloService service;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<html lang=\"en\">");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet HelloServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet HelloServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<p>" + sayHello("world") + "</p>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }

    private String sayHello(java.lang.String arg0) {
        try {
        Hello port = service.getHelloPort();
        return port.sayHelloName(arg0);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Ne stana";

    }
}
```

The url code with ?wsdl works fine, it generates the wsdl code. When I call the servlet this is the error I get:

```
5:10:37,075 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

15:10:37,076 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:361)

15:10:37,077 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:350)

15:10:37,078 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)

15:10:37,078 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at soap.endpoints.soap.HelloService.getHelloPort(HelloService.java:72)

15:10:37,078 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at webclient.HelloServlet.sayHello(HelloServlet.java:49)

15:10:37,078 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at webclient.HelloServlet.processRequest(HelloServlet.java:32)

15:10:37,079 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at webclient.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:40)

15:10:37,080 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)

15:10:37,080 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

15:10:37,080 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

15:10:37,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

15:10:37,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

15:10:37,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

15:10:37,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:10:37,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

15:10:37,081 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

15:10:37,082 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:10:37,082 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

15:10:37,082 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

15:10:37,082 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

15:10:37,082 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

15:10:37,083 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

15:10:37,084 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

15:10:37,084 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

15:10:37,084 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

15:10:37,084 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

15:10:37,084 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

15:10:37,084 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

15:10:37,085 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

15:10:37,085 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

15:10:37,085 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

15:10:37,085 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

15:10:37,085 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

15:10:37,085 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

15:10:37,086 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

15:10:37,086 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

15:10:37,086 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)

15:10:37,086 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

15:10:37,086 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

15:10:37,087 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

15:10:37,087 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

15:10:37,087 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:329)

15:10:37,087 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)

15:10:37,087 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:423)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:525)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)

15:10:37,088 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)

15:10:37,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:493)

15:10:37,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.createPort(ProviderImpl.java:578)

15:10:37,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)

15:10:37,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 46 more

15:10:37,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
15:10:37,089 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://soap/}sayHello". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.jaxws_asm.SayHello
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.SayHello
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory.createSayHello(soap.endpoints.soap.SayHello)
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://soap/}sayHelloResponse". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.jaxws_asm.SayHelloResponse
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.SayHelloResponse
15:10:37,094 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory.createSayHelloResponse(soap.endpoints.soap.SayHelloResponse)
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://soap/}sayHelloNameResponse". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.jaxws_asm.SayHelloNameResponse
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.SayHelloNameResponse
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory.createSayHelloNameResponse(soap.endpoints.soap.SayHelloNameResponse)
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://soap/}sayHelloName". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.jaxws_asm.SayHelloName
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    this problem is related to the following location:
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.SayHelloName
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory.createSayHelloName(soap.endpoints.soap.SayHelloName)
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)        at soap.endpoints.soap.ObjectFactory
15:10:37,095 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) 

15:10:37,101 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)

15:10:37,102 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)

15:10:37,102 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)

15:10:37,102 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)

15:10:37,102 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)

15:10:37,103 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)

15:10:37,103 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:10:37,103 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:10:37,103 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:10:37,103 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:392)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:348)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:346)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:346)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:247)

15:10:37,104 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:472)

15:10:37,105 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:327)

15:10:37,105 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 58 more

15:10:37,106 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Test2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I managed to find the solution myself. The problem was on the client side. When executing the command: `wsimport`, a pack of classes was created and in them their

```
 @XmlType(name = "SayHelloName", propOrder = {
    "arg0"
})
```

was not ok. The name was with small first letter which led to the exception. As soon as I changed it, it started working. Hope this answer helps other beginners with JAX-WS